# How to Get Last Update id in Cake PHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to update set of Records, so iam using following code and then i need update the updated row id to another table, so i want to Last Updated Row ID

```
 $this->mymodel->updateAll(array('field1'=>0),array('field5'=>0));
```

Comment: Do you need to know all the IDs of the rows that have been updated, or just the very last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the ID of the last row, you can simply use this getID function:

$this->(Model Name)->getID()

Check out the following reference for more relevant functions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html

Peace! xD :)